# Solenoid switch controller

Tags: switching, solenoid-valve

I’m currently in the process of automating 
my orchard. I have a string of 87 irrigation solenoid valves, 24v 60hz, holding amps is 200 mA.

I would like to connect them in series and use a single switch at each one.  Control them via computer.

So my question: Is there a switch on the market that is activated via signal? I need to be able to activate each switch individually from a single location 
without having to run individual sets of wires to each switch.

Comment: (1) Be careful not to look as though you are asking for product recommendations as this will get your question closed. (2) Did you calculate what voltage you would need for 87 x 24 V to power them all in series? (It's rather high and you're unlikely to have a power supply with that voltage.) (3) You've quoted the holding amps but you will need to get them to switch first, presumably at a higher current. Do you know that value? (4) You could series connect sets of them but the insulation would have to be rated for your mains supply. Update your question with details. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: If you want to control the solenoids individually, you almost certainly should connect them in parallel, rather than series.  You would have a switch (probably a relay = electrically-controlled switch) in series with each solenoid.

Comment: Have you consider an Industrial PLC?

Comment: Each solenoid will still need a master power feed, even if it is switched on/off by remote control.

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested in the comments: put the solenoids in parallel. In fact your idea where you put then in series with a switch for each won't work. As soon as one switch is open none of them will work.

More important: for outside circuitry you want to stick to a low voltage. It is safe.

I think your concern is that you need ~35Amps to have them all on. You could put two of them in series with one switch per pair. You would then need a 48V transformer of ~17.5 Amps. But you still have the same amount of watts so the transformer will be about the same size (and cost).

What also has been mentioned is that the current will be much higher when you switch them on. If you use a computer, you should program it, so it never switches them all on at the same time. That way you can get away with the 35Amps transformer.

You will end up with a bundle of 87 wires. I don't know how these solenoids are placed. If they are far apart you might put a tiny relay at each so you have one set of power cable and very thin control cables. The cost is cable versus an extra relay.

Ultimately you could place a tiny controller (They come in as small as 6 pins) at each solenoid and use a protocol. (e.g. a UART). You need only three wires then, but that may be beyond your capabilities. (It has the advantage that you can interface the system to your computer using a standard USB-serial adapter. )